# Does an NPC provoke an AOO when he attacks one of two adjacent PCs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

I've read the table which lists the various actions that do and do not provoke an AOO and know that an attack doesnt. But I'm unsure of what happens in the following situation.

If two PCs are threatening an enemy and this enemy attacks PC1, does PC2 get an AOO?

Logically speaking, attacking someone leaves you vulnerable to a second adjacent enemy. As far as I know the rules never clarify this situation. Or do they and have I just missed it completely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rules don't "clarify" this situation because it is not a condition that provokes an attack of opportunity. It would list it if it was.

AoOs are only generated by more intense lapses of attention, like stopping to chug a potion of Mountain Dew while threatened.  You are at a disadvantage when ganged up on, and more so if flanked, but you do not provoke AoOs if you are just standing there fighting everyone. If you run off, or try to shoot a bow at them (without a compensating feat), or start casting a spell, sure.

Answer (score 4):

From [the table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Table-Actions-in-Combat):

> Attack (melee): No
>   Attack (ranged)   Yes
>   Attack (unarmed)  Yes

So it depends on what kind of attack.

> Logically speaking, attacking someone leaves you vulnerable to a second adjacent enemy.

If you are engaged in melee combat with a weapon you are able to time your attacks to guard against opponents other than your target.

Having two opponents able to make attacks against you is disadvantage enough.